# How to test if subject is subscribed in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have simple implementation in component which I want to unit test:

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.subscribeToResponse();
}     

subscribeToResponse()
{

this.service.responseSubject.pipe(takeUntil(this.subscribe$)).subscribe(response => {
});
}
```

**Spec file:**

```
describe('myComponent', () => {
  let component: myComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;



  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ myComponent ],
      providers: [service]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddNewAppointmentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create AddNewAppointmentComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('Should subscribe to response from service', ()=>{

    // Arrange
    let service = TestBed.get(service);
    let spy = spyOn(service, 'responseSubject').and.callFake.({ subscribe: () => {} });

    //Act 
    component.subscribeToResponse();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //Assert
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
});
```

But I get:

> Expected spy to have been called.

What has to be done to check if a certain subject is subscribed in the component after calling a function?

**UPDATE**:

Below is body (example)  of my function where I subscribed to subject, After subscribing I perform some actions based on response from subject:

```
this.service.responseSubject.pipe(takeUntil(this.subscribe$)).subscribe(response => {

      if(response[results])
      {
          this.moveToStep2();
      }
      else()
      {
          this.moveToStep1();
      }
    });
    }
```

I want to test that if certain response is returned then a function is called but I don't know how to mock this behavior.

Comment: There is no value is unit testing if a subject has a subscription. You should test the expected behavior of the source code, and if the behavior works as expected then a subscription is therefore mandatory. This seems like a pointless test to me.

Comment: I get your point. Thanks. But What if I have written some logic after subscribing to response and I want to test that?

Comment: You shouldn't test logic. You should test expectations. I know that sounds strange, but the logic is internal to the object. The tests are external. You need to modify your source code so you can verify that the state of the object changed as expected.

Comment: Please update your question with source code that shows what you want to test, what you expect the source code to do and explain why you can't write a test to cover it.

Comment: @Reactgular I have updated code to describe my issue. I need guidance that how subject subscription can be mocked to check if a certain function is called.